# What does the “A” means in the example with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

[Doc of AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetTitle.htm)

```
WinGetTitle, OutputVar [, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
```

Example on the page

```
WinGetTitle, Title, A
MsgBox, The active window is "%Title%".
```

The page doesn't say anything about A. When I replace A with B, it doesn't work.

I want to know what A means. I thought it might be "Active." Where can I find relevant information?

Comment: It even says in the link you posted. :-)

Comment: yeah，it's fool of me, sorry

Comment: you should mark your own answer as accept the correct answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fool. I find the easy answer
[WinTitle.htm](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)

A ===   The Active Window